# windows 7 find and replace string in files and folders

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-7-x64

In windows powershell ISE i'm trying to replace a string in a lot of files name and folders name example i have files and folders like

```
foo_file1.txt
file2_foo.php
file3_foo_file.js
foo/folder1/file.ext
folder2/file4_foo.doc
foo_folder/file5.ppt
folder/foo/file_foo.jpg
```

I want to change all "foo" to "bar" for example. I used windows powershell command

```
$dir = "the Path of folder Parent"
CD $dir
Get-Childitem -recurse | 
Where-Object {$_.Name -match "foo"}
rename-item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "foo", "bar" }
```

but this command is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-Childitem -recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "foo"} | % {  Rename-Item -NewName ( $_.Name -replace "foo", "bar" ) -Path $_.FullName }
```

Seems that you forgot the `-Path` parameter of `Rename-ITem`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this also:

```
$dir = "C:\folderpath"
(Get-Childitem $dir -recurse |Where-Object {$_.Name -match "foo"}) | 
rename-item -NewName { $_.BaseName -replace "foo", "bar" }
```